# MySQL drop downs

Tags: php, mysql

I have 1 table named restaurants and this holds the restaurant details such as Name, Address etc.

I am looking to create a review section which allows users to rate and review through a form for each restaurant. At the moment I have 2 drop down menus in my form one for County and the other for RestaurantName, I would like the user to choose a County and then for the next dropdown to be populated with only the restaurants in that County.

What is the best way to do this?

If you need any more info let me know. I currently have both dropdowns populated with data from mySql table, but it is showing all restaurants currently.

drop.php

```
 <?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "B00606958", "uHmB4jRw") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - location of mysql server, 

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

        mysql_select_db("b00606958") or die(mysql_error());
        /* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */
        ?>




<?php 

$query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT County FROM restaurants") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
        $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
        $.get('loadsubcat.php?parent_cat=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#sub_cat").html(data);
            $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }); 
    });

});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="get">
    <label for="category">County</label>
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
        <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['County']; ?>"><?php echo $row['County']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Restaurant</label>
    <select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

loadsubcat.php

```
mysql_connect("localhost", "B00606958", "uHmB4jRw") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
    /*
        localhost - location of mysql server, 

        if connection fails it will stop loading the page and display an error
    */

        mysql_select_db("b00606958") or die(mysql_error());
        /* tutorial_search is the name of database we've created */


$parent_cat = $_GET['parent_cat'];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT RestaurantID FROM restaurants WHERE County = {$parent_cat}");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo "<option value='$row[RestaurantID]'>$row[RestaurantName]</option>";
}

?>
```

Table Structure:

Tbl name = restaurants

1   RestaurantName  varchar(255)

2   AddressLine1    varchar(100)

3   AddressLine2    varchar(100)

4   Town    varchar(50)

5   County  varchar(50)

6   Postcode    varchar(7)

7   Telephone   varchar(11)

8   Email   varchar(50)

9   Website varchar(100)

10  NoOfDishes  int(255)

11  RestaurantID    bigint(20)

12  Rating  int(5)

Comment: Your Target Can Be Achieved Through AJAX. Please Share Your Tried Code, I Will Try To Help ASAP.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into this and if no joy will get back to you :)

Comment: @NanaPartykar I have added in my code so far,  I am able to populate the County dropdown with no problems, and it is getting as far as loading my GIF file, but the second dropdown is empty?

Comment: @NanaPartykar If any help I have been following this tutorial - http://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/php/5568/creating-dependent-dropdown-list-php-jquery-and-ajax.html

Comment: Share your `County` & `restaurants` DB table structure @SLC .

Comment: Please tell `column name` of both the tables @SLC.

Comment: @NanaPartykar County RestaurantID, RestaurantName are all part of the one table called restaurants.  I've added my structure above ^

Comment: Which column name of `restaurants` table is auto-increment ?

Comment: @NanaPartykar RestaurantID is set as the primary key and to Auto-Increment.

Answer (score 0):

You have two way for do this:

1. make an Ajax request when user change the Country select value;
2. register a reference to the Country in the Restaurant options; when user change the Country  hide  every Restaurant select that doesn't match the reference to selected Country (the implementation depends on which language you're using);

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't write `connection code` in each and every page. Write in one page & include in each page where it requires. I created one page namely **dbConnection.php** page.

Use this code. And, if any error comes. Feel free to ask.

**dbConnection.php**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "B00606958", "uHmB4jRw") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("b00606958",$con) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

**drop.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Dependent DropDown List</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include('dbConnection.php');?> //connection here.
<form method="get">
    <label for="category">County</label>
    <select name="parent_cat" id="parent_cat">
        <?php 
        $query_parent = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT County FROM restaurants") or die("Query failed: ".mysql_error());
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_parent)): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['County']; ?>"><?php echo $row['County']; ?></option>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </select>
    <br/><br/>

    <label>Restaurant</label>
    <div class="RestaurantDiv"></div>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#parent_cat").change(function() {
      $(this).after('<div id="loader"><img src="images/loading.gif" alt="loading subcategory" /></div>');
      var county = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({url:"loadsubcat.php?parent_cat="+county,cache:false,success:function(result){
        $(".RestaurantDiv").html(data);
        $('#loader').slideUp(200, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }});
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

**loadsubcat.php**

```
<?php
include('dbConnection.php');
$parent_cat = $_GET['parent_cat'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM restaurants WHERE County = {$parent_cat}");
?>

<select name="sub_cat" id="sub_cat"></select>
<?
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {?>
    <option value="<?echo $row['RestaurantID'];?>"><?php echo $row['RestaurantName']?></option>
<?}?>
</select>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work, I am still able to select from the County dropdown but the Restaurant drop down does not show at all.

Comment: Have you created `<div class="RestaurantDiv"></div>` as i created in `drop.php`. You copied whole code or not @SLC ?

Comment: Yes I removed all existing code, and replaced with your code